# Supabase relation one to many

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I'm new to supabase, and I'm creating a very simplified Facebook clone to learn the main features. I'm trying to link comments to a post, so I created a comments table (with columns: id, profile, text) and then a posts table (with columns: id, text, created_by, comment_ids).
I linked the comment_ids column, to the comments.id table, but it allows me to add only one comment to each post, while I would like to link multiple comments to a single post.

Is it possible to link multiple rows of a table to a single row of another table?

I'm trying to create a column like this:

```
comment_ids: ["id-1", "id-2", "id-3", ...]
```

Comment: You could do something like, have a thread id for the post its self.  Then have a table that has a column that has the ID value of the Thread key, and then you can use that  column to link all the similar comments to the same post.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to store values in a column with commas, esepcially if you want to modify those values later, reorder them, or allow a comma to be part of the string.   You can than do an Insert statement for each new comments, instead of having to do an update, find the order of the id , it was the 15th one in the pair for example, thats very inefficient to loop through 14 things to get to the 15th one we need for example.  Whereas if all the comments were in one table and all the threads in another, you can pull the comments for that thread just by feeding it the Thread ID.

Comment: @easleyfixed Thanks for the reply, I will try to follow your suggestions

Comment: Good luck, trust me once you master that, you will find you can use it many other places in your design.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would want to also store the Id of the post on the comment table as well. This way you can tie every comment to a particular post.

[image]